# Supermicro x8, x9 set some settings by cli

Tags: ipmi, supermicro

We have many servers supermicro x8xxx, x9 xxx and I wanna set smtp, hostname settings by script. For this I need some cli útil or interface. I know about smcipmitool, but it can set smtp only for x10. Are there any another way? In documentation there is very few information about Smash, maybe I can use it?

Comment: does it have to be via CLI? The web interface will allow you to add SMTP settings.

Comment: Only cli. It is fotr automatization. But, you are right, final decision is with web xDD [link](https://gist.github.com/mykolq/b0cd188cd5fc6f3296c55e98bc9ba121)

Comment: You can create condicional clauses and make some iteration. It's just example of using cli.